# SharpZipLib GetInputStream

Tags: .net, sharpziplib

I've built a webapplication in which a user can select a zipfile from their filesystem (via an asp:FileUpload). Then the application unzips the zipfile and ftp's every file.

here's the code:

```
Public Sub Unzip(ByVal str As Stream, ByVal constr As String)
    Dim zf As New ZipFile(str)
    Dim ze As ZipEntry
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < zf.Count
        ze = zf.EntryByIndex(i)
        i = i + 1
        Dim ftp As New ftpItem(constr)
        ftp.upload(ze.Name, "pic", zf.GetInputStream(i), ze.Name, ze.Name)

    End While
    zf.Close() 
End Sub
```

The ftpItem class is a class of my own which handles the ftp.
ftp.upload needs as third parameter the stream for the file to be sent.

But for some reason zf.GetInputStream(i) always gives nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you should increment `i` inside the loop **AFTER** you call `GetInputStream`.  If there is only one file this logic will always fail, I imagine.

```
While i < zf.Count
    ze = zf.EntryByIndex(i)

    Dim ftp As New ftpItem(constr)
    ftp.upload(ze.Name, "pic", zf.GetInputStream(i), ze.Name, ze.Name)

    i = i + 1

End While
```

If that does not work, there is a purportedly working C# example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328343/using-sharpziplib-to-unzip-specific-files), using a different method `GetNextEntry` to iterate the list of compressed files.

Comment: Moving to the begining does not help. still the same result.  the increment was indeed in the wrong place. But even placing it right does not help. The entries I get are good, if I run the debugger and I ask ze.Name, it gives me the names of the files; just like ze.Size gives me the right size for the files. (I've also tried iterating like the c# example with no luck)

Comment: @user495089 - is that comment for me, or the answer below?  Seems to me like you have a simple logic error here

Comment: Have you tried just writing the uncompressed data to a local file (`FileStream`) or `MemoryStream` instead of using FTP?  What do properties look like on `zf.GetInputStream()`?  What it the interface to `upload`?  Just a `Stream`, or some other class as param 3?

Comment: @Ivo - great, glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are at the end of the stream, try moving to the begining of the stream so you can read everything.

```
str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```