# How to read file from zip folder without extracting in asp.net 2 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, zip, using

I want to read a file from a zip folder in Asp.net 2.0 using C# . actually i want something like this :

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Open(@"E:\MyZipFolder.ZIP", FileAccess.Read))
{
    // Read the central directory collection
    List<ZipFile.ZipFileEntry> dir = zip.ReadCentralDir();

    // Look for the desired file
    foreach (ZipFile.ZipFileEntry entry in dir)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(entry.FilenameInZip) == "MyZipFile.jpg")
        {
            // File found, extract it
            zip.ExtractStoredFile(entry, @"E:\ExtractFolder\MyZipFile.jpg");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

ZipFile is unknown , is there any suggestion?

Comment: What does mean "ZipFile is unknown"?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967864/how-to-read-data-from-a-zip-file-without-having-to-unzip-the-entire-file

Comment: ZipFile is 4.5 feature, for asp.net 2.0 you can use [ziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

Comment: You could also check the [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging(v=vs.85).aspx) classes in .NET 3.0+

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into [DotNetZip Library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead.

> To use the zip capability in your applications, you need to be using
>   the .NET Framework 2.0 or later, and you need the DotNetZip Devkit
>   assembly.

**Edit**:  To extract a file by name:

From http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html# "Navigation: Code Examples -> C#"

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
  ZipEntry e = zip["MyReport.doc"];
  e.Extract(OutputStream);
}
```

Comment: I Use .net framework 2.0 and download ionic.zip.dll but actually i want to know how can i extract just one of those files which are in a zip file because my zip file is too large and i don't want to extract all files in my web application . please guide how can i do it .