# Edit Content of WAR file in C#

Tags: c#, war

I have a java WAR file and I want to edit a file in it without decompressing it. Because the file is large it can take a long time to decompress and compress it again. 
I use `SharpZipLib` in `C#` for working with zip files, but I can't find a solution to edit some data in internal folders. 
For example I want to edit a file with this path: `file.war\dir1\dir2\a.txt` and replace some text in it. do you have any solution?

**EDIT:**

It may be irrelevant, but 
I am almost sure this can be implemented, because I searched and found that `WinRAR Software` has this capability.

Comment: Would you be able to extract just that file, edit it, and zip it again?

Comment: I think i did not understand what you mean@hmartinezd , can you explain more? how can i do that?

Comment: Well, actually you may be right, is probably that unzipping a single file will take as long as unzipping then all. But that's something I am not completely sure.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967864/how-to-read-data-from-a-zip-file-without-having-to-unzip-the-entire-file

Comment: Extract, alter, delete original, re-add might work. You can't just "remove" bytes in the middle of a file though, so the archive might get larger with each operation.

Comment: I am also looking for the exact same thing. i am making a tool to automatically set beans.xml attributes... it is possible manually with 7ZIP- open archive and edit the file, but what i believe they do is extract the file into temp directory and let you edit it, when you close the editor the add it back to the archive.