# FileListEntry to ExcelWorksheet in Blazor ServerSide

Tags: c#, blazor

trying to manipulate some Excelfiles data stored in a zip file.

the idea is -> User have to upload to the app an zip file withe excelsheet inside
and the blazor app have to give back a single one mixed sheet when user click on a download button.

i successed to get an FileListEntry with the zip file but don'know how to search for sheet inside it to manipulate data...

i use epplus v4
blazor serverside

if someone know how
thanks.

Comment: This question is lacking in details and is not appropriate for StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you share some code, but I assume what you want to do is find an excel file inside an uploaded zip file.

You can use this nugget library [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) to open and read the zip file and its contents:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
    ZipEntry e = zip["Excel.xlsx"];
    e.Extract(OutputStream);
}
```

Took this code sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968482/1158845)

Comment: Thank you Umair , actualy, i tried to test it but i cannot even transfom my IFilieListEntry  into ziparchive object ... i use BlazorInputFile(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OudZqyeHxg) to make the upload and i succes to get the file in object with IFileListEntry implementation but dont know how to use it after to search and get my excel file into it...

Comment: The `IFileListEntry` has a `.Data` property which is a memory stream which you can used in [`ZipFile.Read`](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/blob/590a6d89ee7e4d79b24abf7deb928cf9456f08d9/src/Zip.Shared/ZipFile.Read.cs#L412) as this can also accept a `Stream` object.

Comment: it seems not working... 
i tried : 
Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(MyIFileListEntry.Data);

seem return me a null object...

Comment: cant find the way to get the excel from the zip...
i succes to get the excelpackage (epplus) from the zipentry but cant get the sheet or workbook inside it ...
i see in the debug inside the excelpackage the xls file but cannot use it, work with it....
clue? i saw that is a readonly file ...