# Find out what packages, classes and methods the Jar file contains

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, jar, editor

I have a Java code editor with syntax highlighting, with a code hint menu and quick actions. The editor is written in C#. Once again, this editor is for editing Java code! I need to know what packages, classes, methods are in the Jar library (Jar file) for further
code hinting and syntax highlighting.

I have an idea about decompiling the Jar to find out "its contents", but I suspect that there is another more efficient way to implement this.

This is what my editor looks like: [image]

Comment: apparently a .jar file is just a .zip archive, you can access it as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762855/2430796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be relatively simple. I found the 'jd-gui' repository (https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui), here is the app: (http://java-decompiler.github.io/). The program itself is written in java and is a very good java decompiler based on the jd-core core (https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-core).

I liked this application, because. it implements a detailed overview of the entire decompiled application (you can see what packages, classes, methods, fields are in the jar), that's exactly what I needed! Because it was an open source repository, I just tweaked it a little, and now when decompiling, the program saves the xml file with the "contents of the jar file". And then I wrote an xml parser in c# to load data and further work with them. That's all...

Code with edited jd-gui saving xml file with jar content: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_opg0BBIrmHoZ125F0Fyl9n_0o4xutiL?usp=sharing When loading a jar file, next to it (in the same folder) an xml file with the contents of this file will be saved.